# Java - How to connect to wireless network if it already exists?

Tags: java, android

I am using the code below to create a wireless profile on an android phone. For some reason it creates a new profile each time so the phone will have multiple profiles for the same wireless network. Is there a way to have it not create a new profile if it already exists?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IVMOBILEActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
    TextView status = new TextView(this);                  


    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();  
    wc.SSID = "\"MyNetwork\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!! 

    wc.hiddenSSID = true; 
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;      
    wc.priority = 10; 
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);  
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"Password\""; 
    WifiManager  wifiManag = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true); 
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res ); 
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration(); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es ); 
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);    
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );   

    tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
            "Version 1.0");

    status.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");

    try {

        Thread.sleep(5000);

         ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

         if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  
                //You are connected, do something online. 
                setContentView(tv);

            }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
                //Not connected.         
               setContentView(status);
            }  

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and see if it exists first before adding it to the `WifiManager`. Pseudocode for example:

```
//Check if this SSID is already stored. If it is, return that configuration.
//If not, return the configuration being tested.
public WifiConfiguration checkPreviousConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wc) {
    List<WifiConfiguration configs = wifi.getConfigurations();
    for(WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
        if(config.SSID.equals(wc.SSID)) return config;
    }
    return wc;
}

//......
int res = wifi.addNetwork(checkPreviousConfiguration(wc));
```

Make sense?

EDIT: Obviously, you'll probably want to check against other factors beyond just the SSID (since an SSID is not necessarily a unique identifier), and check against those prior to constructing a new `WifiConfiguration` instance, but this is kind of the idea that I would start with.

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you know how I would wrap a progress bar around this so I can show the status?

Comment: I mean, I can't imagine the delay on a method like this would be long enough to even be noticeable to a user. But no, I don't have any experience with progress bars on Android -- that'd be best left to a separate question.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestions